# Look up data across many sheets in the same workbook

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet to keep track of golf skins/sweeps stats for a group I play with. I'm currently trying to keep track of each night we play as a separate sheet and I want to have a summary page that shows stats for everyone that pulls data from all the weekly sheets. There will be 30-40 sheets so referencing each one individually will be unmanageable.

Also, data for each golfer may not be in the same cell(s) on each sheet depending if people join the group throughout the year. I don't want to have to edit all the previous weeks to make everything line up. I did find an example that should work in Excel but it's not working with Google Sheets. It's only pulling data from the first weekly sheet. Here's the formula I have for one of the cells, but it's similar for most calculations

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&weeks&"'!A2:A100"),A2,INDIRECT("'"&weeks&"'!C2:C100")))
```

weeks is a named range that contains all the sheet names.
Column A contains names. This formula will find the name in A2 on all sheets in the named range and sum every corresponding value on the weekly pages in column C. Right now this only reads the first weeks sheet. This particular column is if they paid that week so I have a total of how much they paid for the season. The same type of calculation will be done for each person and for various other stats.

Any help on how to accomplish this or even take a different approach would be helpful.

EDIT to add an example sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rVXZ4Ia3EJec2mQYJkXDQM3umrtA782vs23Kr19coGU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: added a link in the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this accounts for 20 sheets even if they do not exist yet:

```
=QUERY({
 IFERROR('1'!A2:C,  {"","",""});
 IFERROR('2'!A2:C,  {"","",""});
 IFERROR('3'!A2:C,  {"","",""});
 IFERROR('4'!A2:C,  {"","",""});
 IFERROR('5'!A2:C,  {"","",""});
 IFERROR('6'!A2:C,  {"","",""});
 IFERROR('7'!A2:C,  {"","",""});
 IFERROR('8'!A2:C,  {"","",""});
 IFERROR('9'!A2:C,  {"","",""});
 IFERROR('10'!A2:C, {"","",""});
 IFERROR('11'!A2:C, {"","",""});
 IFERROR('12'!A2:C, {"","",""});
 IFERROR('13'!A2:C, {"","",""});
 IFERROR('14'!A2:C, {"","",""});
 IFERROR('15'!A2:C, {"","",""});
 IFERROR('16'!A2:C, {"","",""});
 IFERROR('17'!A2:C, {"","",""});
 IFERROR('18'!A2:C, {"","",""});
 IFERROR('19'!A2:C, {"","",""});
 IFERROR('20'!A2:C, {"","",""})}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  order by sum(Col3) desc 
  label sum(Col3)''")
```

[image: 0]